# When is a vtable destroy in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is calling **a virtual function in the destructor of a base class** is a good practice? And "*Does vtable exist in destruction time? And is calling a virtual function in the destructor recommended?*"

Comment: Vtables are static data structures associated with classes, not objects.

Comment: Post some code that illustrates what you are asking about.

Comment: Vtable is a static object of polymorphism classes. But Vtable is a pointer actually. And I would be glad if I know when this pointer will be deleted?

Answer (score 4):

> Can I call a virtual function in the destructor of a base class?

Calling virtual functions from destructors or constructors is a bad practice. See the standard (emphasis mine):

> **12.7 Construction and destruction**
> ....
>   Member functions, including virtual functions (10.3), can be called during construction or destruction (12.6.2).
>   When a virtual function is called directly or indirectly from a constructor or from a destructor, including
>   during the construction or destruction of the class’s non-static data members, and the object to which the
>   call applies is the object (call it `x`) under construction or destruction, ***the function called is the final overrider
>   in the constructor’s or destructor’s class and not one overriding it in a more-derived class. If the virtual
>   function call uses an explicit class member access (5.2.5) and the object expression refers to the complete
>   object of `x` or one of that object’s base class subobjects but not `x` or one of its base class subobjects, the
>   behavior is undefined***.

You can find this recommendation in many sources, including Scott Meyers'
**Effective C++: 55 Specific Ways to Improve Your Programs and Designs**
(*Item 9: Never call virtual functions during construction or destruction.)*

or Herb Sutter's
**C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices** (*49. Avoid calling virtual functions in constructors and destructors*).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the object will have a pointer to its vtable when you call the destructor.

The standard explicitly says it is possible to call virtual functions in the destructor, and says what happens.  There is agreement that even though it is allowed it is a bad practice, because it is inherently brittle code that leads to surprises with apparently innocent changes.

If you have that `DerDer` inherits from `Der`, which inherits from `Base`, all of them override member function `void member()`, and you are in the destructor of `Der`, and call `member()`, you are calling `Der::member()`, not `DerDer::member()`, because the `DerDer` part of your object is GONE, DESTROYED already.  A base class can refer inadvertently to data in a derived class, for example:

```
struct Base {
    int *ip;
    Base(int *ip): ip(ip) {}
    virtual void useInt() { std::cout << *ip << std::endl; }
    ~Base() { useInt(); }
};
struct Der: Base {
    int theInt;
    Der(): Base(&theInt) {}
    void useIntPointer() override { std::cout << theInt << std::endl; }
};
```

When an object of type `Der` gets deleted, there is "undefined behavior":  First the implicit destructor of `Der` is called, then the explicit destructor of `Base`, `Base::~Base`.  At that point `Base::ip` is referring to a member of `Der` that has already been destroyed.

Comment: Your answer could be quite nice if you worked it over a little bit. First, in your text you're referring to stuff which just isn't there in the source code (like `void member()`, `class DerDer`, etc.). Second, the thing you point out would be problematic even without `useInt()` being virtual, but just because you let `ip` point to a member of `Der`, i.e. `Der::theInt`. So, it doesn't illustrate the point. Why don't you just override `useInt` in `Der` and access `theInt` from there, or even better access some heap allocated resource which has already been deleted? I think would be much nicer.